# How mod calculate

Tags: haskell

I have following operation:

```
Prelude> mod (3 - 12) 7
```

As result I've got 5.

Why is the result is 5?

And when I try something like this:

```
Prelude> mod -9 7
```

Then I've got error:

```
<interactive>:6:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: Num (t -> a -> a -> a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a t.
              (Num (t -> a -> a -> a), Num (a -> a -> a), Num t, Integral a) =>
              a -> a -> a
```

Why?

I've forgot to mention, that I just start learning haskell.

Comment: You have to enclose negative numbers in parenthesis: `mod (-9) 7`.

Comment: For your second question, try `mod (-9) 7`. `-` is a the only unary operator in Haskell, but to get it to parse as such, you often need extra parens.

Comment: This is not the only question in this post. Why close it?

Comment: Reopened, sorry @melpomene and everyone involved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`mod` is specified](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:mod) as

> integer modulus, satisfying
>
> ```
> (x `div` y)*y + (x `mod` y) == x
> ```

and `div` as

> integer division truncated toward negative infinity

In your case `x` is `-9` and `y` is `7`.

-9 / 7 is -1.2857..., which (rounded down) is -2. Thus `` (-9) `div` 7 `` is `-2`.

Looking at the equation above, we have `` ((-9) `div` 7)*7 + ((-9) `mod` 7) == (-9) ``, which becomes `` (-2)*7 + ((-9) `mod` 7) == (-9) ``, which in turn simplifies to `` (-14) + ((-9) `mod` 7) == (-9) ``, `` (-9) `mod` 7 == (-9) - (-14) ``, and finally `` (-9) `mod` 7 == 5 `` (because -9 + 14 is 5).

---

As for your second question: Haskell parses `mod -9 7` as `mod - (9 7)`, i.e. take the `mod` function and subtract from it the result of applying `9` to `7`. This makes no sense because `9` is not a function (so you can't apply it) and `mod` is not a number (so you can't subtract from it).<sup>1</sup>

The fix is to use `mod (-9) 7` to force `-` to be parsed as a unary operator (negating `9`) instead of a binary infix operator.

<sup>1</sup> As the error message hints, there actually is a way to make ghc swallow this code. It involves defining interesting instances of `Num`, but I won't go into that here.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as is already specified in the comments, if you write `-9` without brackets, it is interpreted as a function, not as a negative number.

Now for the `mod` part: there is a difference between **modulo** ([`mod :: Integral i => i -> i -> i`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:mod)) and **remainder** ([`rem :: Integral i => i -> i -> i`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#v:rem)):

> ```
> mod :: Integral i => i -> i -> i
> ```
>
> integer modulus, satisfying
>
> ```
> (x `div` y)*y + (x `mod` y) == x
> ```
>
> ---
>
> ```
> rem :: Integral i => i -> i -> i
> ```
>
> integer remainder, satisfying:
>
> ```
> (x `quot` y)*y + (x `rem` y) == x
> ```

So if both the *numerator* and denominator are positive, there is no difference, because the `quot` (which is division truncated towards zero) and `div` (floored division) are equivalent.

However when the **numerator** is negative, `mod` will still be positive, because the `div` is floored, and this (`(div x y)*y`) will be lower or equal to the actual result. Whereas the `rem` will be negative.

If on the other hand the **denominator** is negative, the result `mod` will be negative, whereas for the `rem` it will again depend on the sign of the sign of the numerator.

So `mod` always takes the sign of the denominator whereas for `rem` it depends on the sign of the numerator.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are expecting -2. The mathematical definition of modulo is a natural number ( >=0), so it has to return 5 (-2 +7) instead of -5.

If you want a function which returns -2 instead (as most languages do) you can use the `rem` function (remainder)